# How to replace layers?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, cclayer

I started to learn Objective-C and use cocos2D about 1 month ago.

I want to replace three different layers by tapping buttons.
At first, I tried to use "CCLayerMultiplex." Then, use "if sentence." But then the layers just overlap or crash when the buttons are tapped. I want the previous layer to disappear when the new layer appears, but the old layer remains with my code now.

I think using "CCLayerMultiplex" is my best option, but I can't make it work as I want it to.
Below is my code. I'm afraid that there're some poor sentences...

```
@interface GSLayout : CCLayer {
// button items
CCMenuItemImage *file1;
CCMenuItemImage *file1Pushed;
...


// Layer  (replace)
CCLayer *layer1;
CCLayer *layer2;
CCLayer *layer3;


// replace layers
CCLayerMultiplex* mpLayer; 
}

@end




@implementation GSLayout
-(id) init{
if( (self=[super init])) {
    CCLOG(@"%@: %@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), self);

    self.isTouchEnabled = YES;

    // buttons 
    file1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Icon-Small-50.png"
                                                         selectedImage: @"Icon-Small.png"
                                                                target:nil
                                                              selector:nil];
    file1Pushed = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Icon-Small.png" 
                                                          selectedImage:@"Icon-Small-50.png" 
                                                                 target:nil
                                                                selector:nil];
    CCMenuItemToggle *toggleFile1 = [CCMenuItemToggle itemWithTarget:self
                                                            selector:@selector(selectOne:)
                                                               items:file1,file1Pushed, nil];
    toggleFile1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);       


    file2 = [[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Icon-Small-50.png"
                                                    selectedImage: @"Icon-Small.png"
                                                           target:nil
                                                         selector:nil]retain];
    file2Pushed = [[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"Icon-Small.png" 
                                                           selectedImage:@"Icon-Small-50.png" 
                                                                  target:nil
                                                                selector:nil]retain];
    CCMenuItemToggle *toggleFile2 = [CCMenuItemToggle itemWithTarget:self
                                                            selector:@selector(selectTwo:)
                                                               items:file2,file2Pushed, nil];
    toggleFile2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5f, 0.5f);

    ...

    CCMenu *toggleMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:toggleFile1,toggleFile2,toggleFile3, nil];
    [toggleMenu alignItemsHorizontally];
    toggleMenu.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 1.0f);
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    toggleMenu.position = CGPointMake(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height);

    [self addChild:toggleMenu];      


    // create layers
    layer1 = [GameFile1 node];
    layer2 = [GameFile2 node];
    layer3 = [GameFile3 node];
    mpLayer = [CCLayerMultiplex layerWithLayers:layer1,layer2,layer3, nil];

        }
return self;
}

- (void) selectOne: (CCMenuItem*) menuItem 
{
NSLog(@"The first menu was called");
 if([layer1 isRunning])
 {
  nil;       
  NSLog(@"The layer1 is running");
 } else if([layer2 isRunning]) {
   [mpLayer switchTo:0];     
   NSLog(@"The layer2  was replaced");
 }else if([layer3 isRunning]) {
   [mpLayer switchTo:0];             
   NSLog(@"The layer3  was replaced");
 } else{
   [self addChild:layer1];
   NSLog(@"The layer1 was called");
 }

 }

- (void) selectTwo: (CCMenuItem*) menuItem 
{
NSLog(@"The second menu was called");

if([layer2 isRunning])
{
  nil;          
  NSLog(@"The layer2 is running");
} else if([layer1 isRunning]) {
  [mpLayer switchTo:1];
  NSLog(@"The layer1  was replaced");
} else if([layer3 isRunning]) {
  [mpLayer switchTo:1];
  NSLog(@"The layer3  was replaced");
}else{
  [self addChild:layer2];
  NSLog(@"The layer2 was called");
}

}

- (void) selectThree: (CCMenuItem*) menuItem 
{
NSLog(@"The third menu was called");
    ...

}
```

Please give me some advice!
Thank you in advance!

I'll add some codes.

```
@interface GameFile1 : CCLayer {
CCSprite* sprite;
}

@implementation GameFile1
-(id) init{
if( (self=[super init])) {

    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
    CCMenuItemImage *soundItem1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"button1.png"
                                                         selectedImage: @"Icon.png"
                                                                target:self
                                                              selector:@selector(doSomethingOne:)];        

    CCMenuItemImage *soundItem2 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"button2.png"
                                                         selectedImage: @"Icon.png"
                                                                target:self
                                                              selector:@selector(doSomethingTwo:)];

    ...




    CCMenu * myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:soundItem1, soundItem2,soundItem3,soundItem4, soundItem5,soundItem6,soundItem7, soundItem8,soundItem9,soundItem10,soundItem11,soundItem12, nil];


    [myMenu alignItemsInRows:[NSNumber numberWithInt:4],[NSNumber numberWithInt:4],[NSNumber numberWithInt:4] ,nil];



    myMenu.position = CGPointMake(370, 120);


    [self addChild:myMenu];


    sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"o0400026611355530621.jpg"];
    sprite.scale = 0.5f;    
    sprite.position = CGPointMake(screenSize.width/2, screenSize.height/2);
    sprite.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0);

    [self addChild:sprite];

- (void) doSomethingOne: (CCMenuItem  *) menuItem 
{
NSLog(@"The first menu was called");

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"one.wav"];

[sprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: @"one.jpg"]];

}


- (void) doSomethingTwo: (CCMenuItem  *) menuItem 
{
NSLog(@"The second menu was called");

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"two.wav"];

[sprite setTexture:[[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage: @"one.jpg"]];
}
...

@end
```

Comment: Could you specify how `GameFile*` are defined?

Comment: I gave up using layers and try to use scenes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already loaded the textures for all three layers, you might as well have all three sitting in separate CCLayers where two are hidden at any given state using a method similar to:

```
- (void) setLayer:(uint)show {
    layerOne.visible = (show == 0);
    layerTwo.visible = (show == 1);
    layerThree.visible = (show == 2);
}
```